# How do I access Graphics.Gloss Event type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, gloss

I'm attempting to use the Gloss library's `play` function, which takes an event-handling function whose first argument is of type [`Event`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.0.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-Pure-Game.html#t:Event) (according to the [Hackage documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.0.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-Pure-Game.html)). I'm working on Windows with GHC 7.6.3 and Gloss 1.8.0.1.

Here's a sketch of what I'm trying to do:

```
import Graphics.Gloss

type GameState = [Int]

handleInputEvent :: Event -> GameState -> GameState
handleInputEvent _ = id -- Just stubbed in for now
```

The compiler error is:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `Event'
```

If I go into WinGHCI and import Graphics.Gloss and ask it for the type signature of `play`, it looks like this:

```
play ::
  Display
  -> Color
  -> Int
  -> world
  -> (world -> Picture)
  -> (gloss-1.8.0.1:Graphics.Gloss.Internals.Interface.Event.Event
      -> world -> world)
  -> (Float -> world -> world)
  -> IO ()
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the name `Event` clashing with some other module, and thus not being imported in the same way as other symbols from Gloss.

How do I talk to Haskell about Gloss' `Event`?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the link on Hackage in the type signature of `play`, and find that `Event` is exported from [`Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.0.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-Pure-Game.html#t%3aEvent), then simply import that module.

Comment: Thank you! I got home this evening and started going through the code for the Gloss library, importing various things, and figured that out.

Comment: I didn't understand the documentation, I guess; the play function on there is visible without importing Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game, so I assumed the rest of the symbols in there would also be visible.

Comment: @user5014: Yeah, generally a top-level module like this should re-export the definitions of types that it expects clients to use. This was probably an oversight.